# Two views for one controller codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

How to use two views in one controller in codeigniter

```
function index()
{
    $data['title'] =" Details";                      
    $data['courses']=$this->coursemodel->getcourse();
    $data['batches']=$this->coursemodel->getbatchname();
    $this->load->view('admin/fees/coursereport',$data);                      
}
```

first view

```
      $this->load->view('admin/fees/coursedetails',$data);
```

second view

```
       $this->load->view('admin/fees/coursereport',$data);
```

My question is how to use two views in one controller in codeigniter

Comment: What? You're already using three views, what's the problem?

Comment: yup just need to replace the first view or second view

Comment: sorry, I have to down voted your question. You are not clear with what you asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use third parameter of [view()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) and insert the result to another string. Finally, print that string as you like:

```
$FinalOutput = "";
$FinalOutput .= $this->load->view('admin/fees/coursedetails',$data, true);
$FinalOutput .= $this->load->view('admin/fees/coursereport',$data, true);
```

Finally, at the end of your script:

```
$this->load->view('admin/fees/template',array('output' => $FinalOutput));
```

**UPDATE**

I see that you updated your question. If the above is not what you looking for, maybe this is:

```
if( $data['title'] == 'Detail')
    $this->load->view('admin/fees/coursedetails',$data);
else
    $this->load->view('admin/fees/coursereport',$data);
```

The idea here is, by checking what view you really want. Is it what you needed?

Comment: $FinalOutput based on the click of link u meant?

Comment: @soul you're not clear, what's the click you're talking about now?

Comment: updated the answer. Is that (the second answer) what you want? if so, I'll remove the first one.

Comment: @DamienPirsy got confused how to invoke the particular view page i meant

Comment: I give up. "invoke" where and when? is @silent solution what you need? a conditional loading of the view?

Comment: @soul you'd better be clearer next time. +1 to silent for the insight!

Comment: @DamienPirsy   sorry got confused in explaining u.... but silent gave me the solution which i wanted!!! Thanks for ur help silent and DamienPirsy

Comment: so, which one is the answer? the original, or the updated one?